# Present tasks names Python

Tags: python, task

I try to display all the tasks names in the path

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Tasks
```

This is my code:

```
path = 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    print file
```

This is the output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Tasks\Microsoft
```

Can someone see why is this the only output that presented ?

Comment: Which output do you expect?

Comment: Maybe it's because that's the only file in the directory. Incidentally, be careful with backslashes - if you had used lower case, "system32\tasks" would be interpreted as "system32" followed by a tab character followed by "asks". Consider using raw strings for path names.

Comment: What you mean under "Tasks"? `os.listdir` gives you list of existed files/folders in requested directory. Tasks are text files or something?

Comment: In this directory there is a list of the tasks in the computer. Those are files but I want to see only their names. Instead, I get only a directory name that in this directory but not the other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only guessing here, but i'm placing it as the solution:

Your computer has a **64 bit** *Windows* version, but your *Python* installation is **32 bit**.

Due to [Microsoft WOW64 redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx), when accessing the  *C:\WINDOWS\****System32****\Tasks* folder, it is actually accessing *C:\WINDOWS\****SysWOW64****\Tasks*, and therefore you can only "see" the *Microsoft* folder inside.

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is the situation here... there is a way to fix it without install other Python ?

Comment: I don't see a quick one. The recommended way is to install a __64 bit__ _Python_. There's of course the (lame) way of copying the files from one folder to another. Hmm, I think calling  [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx) (using either [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) or [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)) before iterating the folder might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
x = os.popen("tree C:\WINDOWS\System32\Tasks")
x.read()
```

that should give you some output